# How to properly use fire and forget without affecting performance?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage-queues, fire-and-forget

I have asked this question, but couldn't get much response and the ones I get did not solve my problem. So here I'm trying to ask again in a different way.

I have a project that process product feed files into my system. For one certain feed file whole process is taking around 40-50 minutes. Now I have created a `WebJob` to process images from the feed and I'm sending picture urls from my first project to `WebJob` by creating storage client. When I have that to my project, it increased the processing time significantly, so I tried using it with `Task.Run` to use `Fire and Forget` approach, but still even with that overall process time is around 2 hours now.

Here is how I call my method that creates storage queue.

```
if (insertImages)
{
    #pragma warning disable 4014
    Task.Run(async () => { await new QueueUtility().CreateQueueMessage(picture); }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    #pragma warning restore 4014
}
```

And here is my code to create queue message

```
public async Task CreateQueueMessage(Picture picture)
    {
            Utility.Log log = new Utility.Log();
            await AddQueueMessage(picture.url);

    }


public async Task AddQueueMessage(string queueMessage)
    {
        ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ImagekWebJobStorage"));

        // Create the queue client.
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a container.
        CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("imagequeue");

        // Create a message and add it to the queue.
        CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage(queueMessage);
        queue.AddMessage(message);

    }
```

I don't understand why my processing time doubled up and can't find a way to work around that either. Any ideas that would help me resolve this would be really helpful.

<s>EDIT:
Turning `QueueUtility` into static class and methods into static methods seemed to help. Not sure how or why though.</s>

Comment: Is adding to a queue such an expensive operation that you need to do in in the background?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger yes it is increasing my processing time around 40 minutes to at least 1,5 hours

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new CloudStorageAccount, CloudQueueClient, and CloudQueue for every message sent is very inefficient.

You should create these once and reuse them to send each message.

For more guidance on optimizing the performance of applications that use Azure Storage, see:

Microsoft Azure Storage Performance and Scalability Checklist
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-performance-checklist/